# How to update header layout text every seconds in any one activity and display in all screens?

Tags: android, textview

**header.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTime"               
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

i added `header.xml` in all my screen layouts...

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/top_header"
        layout="@layout/header" />
```

Now i want start `timer` and set text of every remaining seconds in text header `txtTime`...
So which screen i write code for countdown timer and set `textview` so all screen display time in `textview`..

can any one suggest me its possible to set text only one screen and display in all screen ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can achieve this using [**AppWidget**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code . It will solve your prolem.

Follow below steps.

```
1) Make one BaseActivity Class.
2) Make One MainActivity Class and extend BaseActivity.
3) Make another SecondActivity class and extend BaseActivity.
```

Here i post all the classes you required .

**What i do in BaseActivity ?**

> I create one Countdown Timer class called MyCount which will display
>   the remaining time .  I create one boolean flag which set false by
>   default . so when user call setHeading() function of BaseActivity it
>   will check the falg if it false then start the timer and if it is true
>   then again set the timer and starts again .

### BaseActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    private TextView textView = null;
    public static MyCount counter = null; 
    private static boolean flag = false;
    private static long millisUntilFinishedVariable = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    protected void setHeading(String message) 
    {
        if(textView == null)
        {
            textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            if(textView != null)
                textView.setText(message);

            if(flag == false)
            {
                counter = new MyCount(30000, 1000);
                counter.start();
            }
            else
            {
                            counter.cancel();
                counter = new MyCount(millisUntilFinishedVariable, 1000);
                counter.start();
            }
        }
    }

    // countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer
    {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
            textView.setText("done!");   //TextView object should be defined in onCreate
            flag = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            millisUntilFinishedVariable = millisUntilFinished;
            flag = true;
            textView.setText("Left:" + millisUntilFinished/1000);// This will be called every Second.
        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity 
{
    private Button buttonClick = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setHeading("Text From Main Activity"); 

        buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class), 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <include layout="@layout/header"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
       android:text="Second Activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### SecondActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        setHeading("From Second Activity");
    }
}
```

### second_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <include layout="@layout/header"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18.0sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SharedPreferences` to save the text to be set to all your screens. Then set the `textViews` with the saved text. You can set the `textView` in the `onCreate()` or `onResume()` of all the activities.

Comment: i need to set textview on every second in countdown timer.. so its update text every seconds ...